# ANR - Input dispatching timed out

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-anr-dialog

My ANR record is going up wildly while getting the following errors:

> MainActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5000ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=false))

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 0000000000086f8c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 00000000001b22c4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #00  pc 00000000003a2764  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::NewLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+492)
  #00  pc 0000000002f90c04  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002457b64  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000024529fc  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000020bdb68  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000023403c8  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000234352c  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000020c2b8c  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f6b9f0  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f6bbb0  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f498fc  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f58618  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f84f04  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f84eb8  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 0000000002f84c78  /data/app/~~1oNF4_Zo6wD4JoCOsMoD2g==/com.google.android.webview-bSyCm6qEZOB-jpRIMNfg2A==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000001a064  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916)
  #00  pc 0000000000019c68  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112)
  #00  pc 0000000000118ac4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8057)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:620)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? We are seeing almost the exact same thing and it also started to happen almost 6 months ago.

Comment: BTW, our app is using Ionic, Capacitor and AngularJS for frameworks.